# Why are Selenium-nodes form a Selenium-grid failing to launch on Jenkins while it runs fine on the Selenium-hub?

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-grid

I have used the following docker-compose to create 1 Selenium-hub, 2 Selenium-nodes(chromium) and a Jenkins server.

**Command used:** docker-compose up --scale chrome=2

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  chrome:
    image: seleniarm/node-chromium
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=seleniarm-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=2
      - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
      - SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=300
    depends_on:
      - seleniarm-hub
    networks:
      - jenkins-network

  seleniarm-hub:
    image: seleniarm/hub
    container_name: seleniarm-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
    networks:
      - jenkins-network

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
    networks:
      - jenkins-network

networks:
  jenkins-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I have triggered scripts from my machine after setting up the remote url with my selenium hub url, and the scripts run fine. So, it's safe to assume that the selenium-hub and selenium-nodes are working fine.

The selenium plugin installed on Jenkins and it connects fine with the Selenium-hub. But, the problem comes with the integration of Jenkins and Selenium-nodes.

After looking into the Jenkins startup log I found the following error:

```
jenkins          | 2023-03-06 05:35:54.088+0000 [id=23] INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#<init>: Selenium node launch failedAccept timed out
jenkins          | 2023-03-06 05:35:54.089+0000 [id=23] WARNING jenkins.model.Jenkins#<init>: Exception in onOnline() for the computer listener class hudson.plugins.selenium.ComputerListenerImpl on the built-in node
jenkins          | java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
jenkins          |  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
jenkins          |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:474)
jenkins          |  at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
jenkins          |  at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
jenkins          |  at hudson.plugins.selenium.process.SeleniumProcessUtils.createSeleniumRCVM(SeleniumProcessUtils.java:96)
jenkins          |  at hudson.plugins.selenium.callables.SeleniumCallable.invoke(SeleniumCallable.java:94)
jenkins          | Caused: java.io.IOException: Selenium node launch interrupted
jenkins          |  at hudson.plugins.selenium.callables.SeleniumCallable.invoke(SeleniumCallable.java:118)
jenkins          |  at hudson.plugins.selenium.callables.SeleniumCallable.invoke(SeleniumCallable.java:23)
jenkins          |  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1192)
jenkins          |  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1175)
jenkins          |  at hudson.plugins.selenium.process.SeleniumJarRunner.start(SeleniumJarRunner.java:42)
jenkins          |  at hudson.plugins.selenium.configuration.global.SeleniumGlobalConfiguration.start(SeleniumGlobalConfiguration.java:50)
jenkins          |  at hudson.plugins.selenium.PluginImpl.startSeleniumNode(PluginImpl.java:503)
jenkins          |  at hudson.plugins.selenium.ComputerListenerImpl.onOnline(ComputerListenerImpl.java:30)
jenkins          |  at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:1025)
jenkins          |  at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
jenkins          |  at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
jenkins          |  at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
```

FYI: I am working on an M1(ARM64) machine.

I checked the Selenium-hub and Selenium-node logs but found nothing noteworthy. But if needed I will add them at the end of this section.

I suspected if it was a Java version issue. But the JDK is same across the Selenium-grid and Jenkins i.e., openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17.

I also tried adding a network in the docker-compose file hoping that the Jenkins and Selenium-nodes  can communicate properly. But it didn't work.

```
networks:
  jenkins-network:
    driver: bridge
```